# How to use message without 'where'(css) in interceptor? Vue3,Andv

Tags: vuejs3, ant-design-vue

The native 'message' methods of antv include 'where'. But the lower version of the browser is not suitable. I want to use this method in the axios intercept. How should the code be written?
vue3 ,andv4.

other

I tried to use the official method, but I didn't succeed and didn't understand what he meant.
I didn't succeed when I tried this example, so I didn't keep trying in the interceptor.

```
<template>
    <contextHolder />
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { message } from 'ant-design-vue';
const [messageApi, contextHolder] = message.useMessage();
messageApi.open({
  content: 'Customize close time',
});
</script>
```